# What to use instead of the as.real?

Tags: r

I've start improving some old R code and find that next functions are [deprecated](http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS.html):

- `real` creates a double precision vector of the specified length. Each element of the vector is equal to 0.
- `as.real` attempts to coerce its argument to be of double type.
- `is.real` returns TRUE or FALSE depending on whether its argument is of double type or not.

And what to use instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, that's pretty old code. I think you'll be fine with `double`, `as.double`, and `is.double`.